# KnockoutScript row sum

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockoutscripts to update all the row elements. 
Do you know what is wrong with the below code, it is not giving the row sum. Any help would be helpful. At the moment, the problem is I am not able to see the rowsum and the grandTotal.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>  <script language="javascript"    type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var rowLine = function () {
              var self = this;
              self.Day1Hrs = ko.observable();
              self.Day2Hrs = ko.observable();
              self.totalrow = ko.computed(function () {
                  return self.totalrow ? parseInt(self.Day1Hrs + self.Day2Hrs) : 0;
              });
          };
          self.addLine = function () { self.lines.push(new rowLine()); };
          self.removeLine = function (line) { self.lines.remove(line); };


          var row = function () {
              var self = this;
              self.lines = ko.observableArray([new rowLine()]);
              self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () {
                  var total = 0;
                  $.each(self.lines(), function () {
                      total += this.totalrow();
                  });
                  return total;
              });

          };

          ko.applyBindings(row());


      });
      </script>
      <table>
      <thead><tr>
                 <th class="Day1Hrs">Day1</th>
                 <th class="Day2Hrs" >Day2</th>
                 <th class="totalrow">Row Total</th>
                 <th>Delete</th>
             </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>

-     <tr>
               <td>
                   <input class="Day1Hrs" data-bind='value:Day1Hrs,      valueUpdate:"afterkeydown"'/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input class="Day2Hrs" data-bind='value:Day2Hrs, valueUpdate:"afterkeydown"'/>
               </td>
               <td  class="totalrow">
                   <span data-bind:'text: totalrow'></span>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <button data-bind='click: removeLine'>Remove Line</button>
               </td>
           </tr>


      </tbody>
      <tfoot></tfoot>
      </table>     <p class="grandTotal">Total <span data-bind='text:grandTotal'/></p>     <button    data-bind='click:addLine'>Add Line</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A jsFiddle would be useful but just scanning the code the following could be the issue:

```
          self.Day1Hrs = ko.observable();
          self.Day2Hrs = ko.observable();

          self.totalrow = ko.computed(function () {
              return self.totalrow ? parseInt(self.Day1Hrs + self.Day2Hrs) : 0;
          });
```

Your observables are initialized as null and you're not getting the value of them correctly.

instead, try:

```
          self.Day1Hrs = ko.observable(0);
          self.Day2Hrs = ko.observable(0);

          self.totalrow = ko.computed(function () {
              return self.Day1Hrs() + self.Day2Hrs();
          });
```